# Did dumb thing and removed GTK3.0 folder

Tags: software-installation, apt

So I removed the folder.  OK...dumb move
Now, when I try to install again....
     sudo apt-get install libgtk-3-dev

It responds:   "libgtk-3-dev is already newest version"

So how can I re-install gtk?  I am still learning Linux so go easy on me pls..

Any ideas?

Comment: And you have done `sudo apt-get remove libgtk-3-dev` before you tried to install it again?

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install libgtk-3-dev
```

The --reinstall flag reinstalls a package that is already installed and at the newest version.

You can read more about apt-get options by reading the manual page (Linux help files) using the man command, so in this case, you would use the following:

```
man apt-get
```

You may also want to read the man page for man pages:

```
man man
```

Comment: Nicely Done!!  That worked perfectly.  I tried the sudo apt-get help, but it didn't help much.  Inexperienced with Linux as I am, I didn't think of MAN.  I came from DOS from long ago in another universe.  There were no manuals, nor real people to help!!  Thanks so much!!